# Python MongoDB datatime in json

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to load mongo data in my django application as a json data.

For that I am using this sample data:

```
mydict = {
"startsAt": {
    "time": {
        "date": datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 1) + timedelta(hours = i)
    },
    "valid": True
}
```

I am inserting above data in my mongo db:

And I am trying to load this data to json using:

```
def filterRegistration():
    sreialise_mongo = json_util.dumps(mycol.find(),indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=default)
    page_sanitized = json.loads(sreialise_mongo)
    return sreialise_mongo
```

And in Django I am loading this data using:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def test(request):
    return Response({"message": filterRegistration()})
```

And I am getting a json data like this:

```
"startsAt": {
        "time": {
          "date": {
            "$date": 1612775312481
          }
        },
        "valid": true
```

And I want a data like:

```
   "startsAt": {
            "time": {
              "date": "2021-01-18T06:21:34.677Z"
            },
    "valid": true
```

I have tried few methods in similar question. But I am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bit fiddly but you have to set the `DatetimeRepresentation` option in the json options to `DatetimeRepresentation.ISO8601`. [Documentation.](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html).

It still puts it in a '$date' field but you code around that.

```
import pymongo
import datetime
from bson.json_util import dumps, JSONOptions, DatetimeRepresentation

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['mydatabase']
mycol = db.mycol

i = 1

mycol.insert_one({
    "startsAt": {
        "time": {
            "date": datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) + datetime.timedelta(hours=i)
        },
        "valid": True
    }})


def filterRegistration():
    json_options = JSONOptions()
    json_options.datetime_representation = DatetimeRepresentation.ISO8601
    serialise_mongo = dumps(mycol.find(), indent=4, sort_keys=True, json_options=json_options)
    return serialise_mongo


print(filterRegistration())
```

gives:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "602133589ebd83ba93ec1583"
        },
        "startsAt": {
            "time": {
                "date": {
                    "$date": "2021-02-07T13:49:28.512Z"
                }
            },
            "valid": true
        }
    }
]
```